# segmentation fault in wxWidgets wxTextCntrl getvalue()

Tags: c++11

I am trying to develop a GUI which uses wxSpinCntrl. While clicking up or down arrow buttons of the SpinCntrl the GUI crashes and shows Segmentation fault. On futher investigation found out that wxTextCntrl GetValue() function to causing this segmentation fault. What could be the possible reason for this?

```
if(TextCtrl != nullptr)                                       
{
  wxString  TextValue = TextCtrl->GetValue();                      
  if(!(TextValue.empty()))                                 
  {
   TextValue.ToDouble(&ReturnValue);                                                 
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While we are willing to help you, we cannot do anything without code, you you have to provide us a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Is it only GetValue() caused segfault? Have you tried calling anything else from this pointer? It can be that object non null but points to the wrong ( uninitialized, or already removed memory ) which leads to segfault.

Comment: Yes, I have tried calling other methods too which also results in segmentation fault.